# Received the US corona virus relief fund check in error, cannot get a hold of IRS to give it back

Tags: united-states, taxes

I lived in the US for about 3 years on a work visa and obtained a SSN (which i actually got from a previous stint there). Once my visa expired I left and am now back in Australia since end of 2018. I filed a US tax return in 2018 but not for 2019.

I still have a US bank account because I saw no reason or obligation (afaik) to close it and I do some work as a foreign contractor and they pay from the US so it is convenient.

Recently the $1200 US govt funds turned up in my account. Clearly the various departments don't talk to each other otherwise they'd realise I wasn't living there any more. After I left the US i was made aware of the 'sailing form' or something you're meant to do when you leave, but it was after I left and I believe part of that needs to be done in person (I left having fully paid up and was tax compliant, in fact i got a refund). It would be great if they mentioned this form when you got your visa.

Anyway, given the coronavirus situation the IRS is not currently taking calls - what do I do? Apart from not wanting to take money from foreign taxpayers when I don't need it (thankfully still employed and doing okay in Aus), I'd like to go back to the US at some point and don't want to jeopardise that.

Comment: I don't know whether or not you're entitled to this payment (as a 2018 resident and tax filer), but the snail-mail contact for the IRS is at https://www.irs.gov/help/contact-my-local-office-internationally .  It may not be any faster than waiting for phone service to resume, but it'll be in the pipeline as dated documentation that you began attempting to rectify the situation.

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://money.stackexchange.com/q/124351/81641

Comment: Thanks for the comments and the links, I thought I'd looked everywhere for a similar post but I guess i was wrong, ta.

Comment: This post seems closer in nature to my query (given that in the one posted above the person was still living and working in US)
https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/124030/im-canadian-but-ive-worked-in-the-united-states-why-did-i-get-a-1-200-payme?rq=1
However the response there seems to suggest that I could, in principle, retain the payment as eligibility is based on the tax year not the current status? Is this indicated *clearly* anywhere to the best of anyone's knowledge?